# USB virtual com port no Bulk_IN tokens

Tags: usb

I write code for usb vcp for my stm32f3 discovery, low level (registers only). After enumeration device sending data to host, but when i open port whit virtual terminal IN requests is stop. I can send OUT data normaly, but no IN tokens(IN endpoint is with payload in it, and valid).

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit, like e.g. provide example code and some info about the environment.

Comment: Code is written  on Mikrobasic. I use descriptors from mikrobasic lib, and theirs win driver. In wireshark everything looks ок, but in one direction (OUT). In debugging mode, Bulk_IN and notification endpoints staying with data in theirs buffers, and  "activated". Seems like host dont care about that. I miss something.....

Comment: Please, put all that into your question, which you can still edit. Make it comprehensible. Maybe add a language tag for the programming language. Add code. At the moment, you supply far from enough information.

Comment: Solved. Corrected  notification endpoint information solve the problem. Waiting host to present Set Control Line State request with wvalue = 3 (DTE = 1, Carrier Control = 1),  then load notification endpoint buffer = 3 (bTxCarrier = 1, bRxCarrier = 1). Sorry mr.Eckhardt because I did not upload the code,but as I said, I do not use libraries, and no one even wants to read the spaghetti. But i like spaghetti....and basic :).